# 32-bit floating point math in 64-bit Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, precision

I program embedded software that runs 32-bit math in 32-bit hardware. I routinely investigate floating point imprecision issues.

In-target debugging is routine, but for convenience I'd like to be able to do quick calculations in my desktop Python environment, having it behave like the target, i.e, do the math in 32 bits.

The desktop hardware, the OS and the Python installation are 64-bit.

We're talking [IEEE floats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) all around.

Ideally, after configuration, I'd like to be able to type, say, `0.1+0.2` at the Python interpreter and have it already know to process and store everything using 32-bit math.

**What are my options?**

Comment: Why not install a 32-bit Python next to your 64-bit installation?

Comment: @TimPietzcker: a 32-bit Python still uses C doubles (i.e. 64-bit values) for Python floats.

Comment: Oh, OK. Well, then it's not that easy, I guess...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending Yann Vernier's idea, this would be a possible transformer that injects a `numpy` import and wraps every `float` literal in `numpy.float32`.

```
import ast

class Float32Visitor(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_Module(self, node):
        # add numpy import
        imp = ast.Import([ast.alias("numpy")])
        node.body = [imp] + node.body
        return node

    def visit_Num(self, node):
        if not isinstance(node.n, float):
            return node

        return ast.Call(
            func=ast.Attribute(
                value=ast.Name(id="numpy", ctx=ast.Load()),
                attr="float32", ctx=ast.Load()
            ),
            args=[node],
            keywords=[],
            starargs=None,
            kwargs=None
        )
```

Hooking this into `compile` is a bit tricky and hackish, however. To do it for a single piece of code, you'd do something like this:

```
import ast
parsed = ast.parse(my_code, "my_code.py", mode="exec")
parsed = Float32Visitor().visit(parsed)
code = compile(parsed, "my_code.py", mode="exec")
my_code = eval(code)
```

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward way is essentially to run a Python built for an environment matching your target, i.e. build it for the target and run it in an emulator on your desktop hardware. Be sure to build it with the appropriate floating point type as the compiler will have software support for wider types. It will be very inefficient but as accurate as your emulator.

If you can make do with just storage behaviour, you can use `numpy.float32` or `ctypes.c_float`, but neither will get you the direct behaviour of mapping floating point literals to that type, and they will likely use 64 or 80 bit operations, which can lead to the rounding differences you want to avoid. The literal remapping is something you could do at an AST level if you wrap your own REPL; while Python has some library assistance for this in the `code` and `ast` modules, it's a fairly complex subject.

Comment: This suggestion doesn't work: the assumption that Python floats are C `double`s internally is fairly deeply embedded in the Python source code (including places where it's assumed that the value for each Python float takes 8 bytes to represent). There's no easy way to configure Python to use the C `float` type instead. It doesn't matter whether the target is 32-bit or 64-bit: it's using 64-bit floats regardless.

Comment: Ah, I apologize. It does require that the compiler breaks the C spec as DBL_DIG is mandated to be >=10. Such violations are not unheard of, though.

Comment: In addition one would want FLT_EVAL_METHOD=0 to maintain the size during operations. I don't think Python is the best language to fulfil this requirement, but I'm not certain of another that will, either; probably using the entire compiler implementation for the target is the easiest way to be sure.